# Python, count the trailing zeros within a factorial

Tags: python, factorial

I am trying to calculate the number of trailing zeros in a factorial.

```
def count(x):
    zeros = 0                     
    for i in range (2,x+1): 
        print(i)
        if x > 0:
            if i % 5 == 0:       
                print("count")    
                zeros +=1       
        else:
            ("False")
    print(zeros)        

count(30)
```

I think the number of trailing zeros is incorrect.

When using `count(30)`, there are 7 trailing `0`'s in 30. However it is returning 6.

Comment: What happens to the number of trailing zeros on the iteration where i = 25?

Comment: there are two 5s in 25, one is unaccounted

Comment: Isn't this program actually just calculating `n//5`?

Comment: this smells of hw. your test case is given by `>>> import math >>> math.factorial(30)
265252859812191058636308480000000`. You will then get more help if you provide your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @tobias_k no :) check this link for trailing zeroes of factorial http://www.mytechinterviews.com/how-many-trailing-zeros-in-100-factorial or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero#Factorial

Comment: @ShawnMehan why else would anyone count the trailing zeros of a factorial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def count (x):
    i = 5
    zeros = 0
    while x >= i:
        zeros += x // i
        i *= 5
    return zeros

print(count(30))
```

Comment: This works thanks, could you explain your code a little if its not a problem?

Comment: this link helps http://www.mytechinterviews.com/how-many-trailing-zeros-in-100-factorial  basically do while loop as long as x >= i, the `zeros += x // i` is this `Number of 5’s = 100/5 + 100/25 + 100/125 + … = 24 (Integer values only)` and just multiply by 5 to get the next multiple of 5 :)

Comment: all has become clear! thank you my friend. it took me a while my brain hurts but I finally understand

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has a [short article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero#Factorial) on this specific topic, which says that this can be computed with a straight-forward summation that counts factors of 5.

```
def trailing_zeros_of_factorial(n):
    assert n >= 0, n
    zeros = 0
    q = n

    while q:
        q //= 5
        zeros += q

    return zeros

# 32! = 263130836933693530167218012160000000
print(trailing_zeros_of_factorial(32)) # => 7
```

Answer (score 1):

We would first count the number of multiples of 5 between 1 and n (which is X ), then the number of multiples of 25 ( ~s ), then 125, and so on.
To count how many multiples of mare in n, we can just divide n by m

```
def countFactZeros(num):
    count = 0
    i = 5
    if num < 0:
        return False
    while num//i > 0:
        count = count + num//i
        i = i * 5
    return count

countFactZeros(10) # output should be 2
countFactZeros(100) # output should be 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm has problem:

```
import math

def count_zeroes(x):
    zeroes = 0
    if x <= 0:
        return zeroes
    for i in range(5, x+1, 5):
        for base in range(int(math.log(i, 5)), 0, -1):
            if i % pow(5, base) == 0:
                zeroes += base
                break
    return zeroes
```

Comment: two for loops is inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
def zeros(n):
    x = n/5
    return x+zeros(x) if x else 0
```